# ASP.NET MVC Cannot find user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have setup an MVC website with Forms Authentication.

Basically, here is the code that has error which says that there is no such user '2010108703' but still, it is logged on (we can see there is a value at User.Identity.Name)

```
 string user = User.Identity.Name;
            Roles.AddUserToRole(user, "student");
            return View();
```

Here is my web.config

```
 <roleManager enabled ="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

so as you can see, we have a value for the current user which is "2010108703"

[image]

but when we are trying to add the role, it says, no such user exist.

[image]

Is it a bug? why is that so?

Thanks

Comment: did you try clearing the cookie of your browser?

Comment: yes softsan i did tried nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormsAuthentication is a separate system from Membership/Roles.  You can put anything you want in the cookie and have the user be logged in, that doesn't mean they exist in your database.

You need to check your login code to make sure that it's actually validating the user against the membership database, and that both membership and roles are using the same connection string.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm just taking a wild guess.**

Since your creating a new ASP.Net MVC, most likely it comes with [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) instead of legacy ASP.Net Membership Provider. ***FYI***: Look at the database tables.

If so, `User.Identity` IPrincipal object is still available in ASP.Net Identity.

However, `Roles` object is not available anymore. Instead, you need to call `UserManager` object.

For example,

`var roleResult = await UserManager.AddUserToRolesAsync(user, new []{"student"});`